# Upgrade from Cypress 8.7.0 to 9.1.0. my project stopped working (I'm using MAC OS)

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

When I'm trying to do `npx cypress open` and then run test cases it gets stuck in `Your test are loading...` and never starts running

Maybe it could be related that I have installed `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` version 2.3.1. Other than that I think I don't have to much to add here.

Comment: Hello @eduardo-uribe, why is it necessary to use cypress-cucumber-preprocessor 2.3.1.?

I'm using cypress 9.1.0 with cypress-cucumber-preprocessor 4.3.0 and both works fine together.

Comment: Hi! I installed 2.3.1 because the new versions of that library has an issue about when you are running by tags and there are some scenarios that are not running you will see in allure report as pending and there are part of failed % test cases

Comment: I installed cypress 9.1.1 and now it's working fine